# Holding input message for error logging

Tags: java, spring, global-variables, wrapper

I have a scenario I'd like to get your input on. We've nearly decided which route we're going to take, but I'm curious what some other opinions regarding a solution are.

Our program is a converter service that sits between two larger systems: System A makes a copy and sticks it on a WebSphere queue, JMS picks it up and starts our service by calling the onMessage method in the Converter class, we do some processing, give it back to JMS, and JMS sticks it on another queue to System B.

We're looking at the best way to capture that input message as soon as it hits our onMessage method and hold onto it throughout our program's entire process. This way if we hit an error, we can print the message that caused said error in our stack-trace log to assist with troubleshooting.

During my research, I came across four methods of obtaining this persistence:

1) Save to a temporary file.

2) Global variable/Singleton.

3) Wrapper class.

4) Spring's dependency injection methods.

The solution we're leaning towards is (ominous music) using a global variable. We're using the following known facts to drive our decision:

- It is only a single String with a max of 1000 characters, so the memory impact is negligible.
- Only one class will ever have access to the setter (the Consumer class it's inside)
- Every other instance will only access the getter.
- Clearest/simplest code, easy for someone following to understand.
- Our service will never become multi-threaded.
- Only one instance of our service will run at one time on a given server.
- The variable will be cleared and overwritten every time a new message comes through.

I know the general opinion is that global variables are very very bad, but I've always been of the opinion that global variables aren't inherently bad, they're just ridiculously easy to use in a bad way. We're of the opinion that this is the one instance where, being mindful of the dangers of global variables, they're the right choice. Your thoughts?

It should be noted that we can't add any libraries to our environment, so we're stuck with whatever we can do with Java and Spring.

Comment: It seems it would be a whole lot simpler to not use the `onMessage()` callback and simply write a loop that reads the messages off the queue.

Comment: Did you consider using a `ThreadLocal` variable ? It acts like a global variable, but it is thread-bounded. It's much more secure as you can't tell when a refactoring or new features will come and make your initial assumptions (like _will never become multi-threaded._) obsolete

Comment: @Brian: Possibly. However we're a little too close to the SAT deadline to be doing too much refactoring.


I haven't come across ThreadLocals (Still a very new Java dev), but I'll look into them. If I can come up with a thread-safe solution as a just in case, all the better.